# If a normal series has maximal lengh in $G$, then it is a composition series.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> A **normal series** of subgroups of $G$ is a decreasing sequence of subgroups
>
> $... \subset G_1 \subset G_0 = G$
>
> where $\subset$ denoted strict inclusion and $\forall i \ \ G_i$ is normal in $G_{i+1}$.
>
> The **length** of series is the number of strict inclusions.
>
> A **composition series** for $G$ is a normal series
>
> $\{e \} = G_0 \subset ... \subset G_{n-1} \subset G_n = G$
>
> such that $\forall i \ \ G_{i+1}/G_i$ is simple.

What I need to prove is that: ***let there be a normal series in $G$ of maximal length. Then it is a composition series.***

Comment: Hint: What happens if one of the factors is not simple?

Comment: @fulges Thank you! I got it and will write an answer.

Comment: That is not what a normal series is. In a normal series every subgroup in the series is normal in $G$. This is completely standard usage, so you should not use it to denote something different. What you describe is called a subnormal series.

Comment: @DerekHolt In two modern abstract algebra books - "Algebra: Chapter 0" by P.Aluffi and "Abstract Algebra" by P.A.Grillet what you call "subnormal series" is called "normal series, though in the latter there is a reference that this object is sometimes called a "subnormal series".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the hint of ***fulges*** in comments, I worked out the following proof:

**Remark:** here $\subset$ means **strict** inclusion.

Let $G_0 \subset ... \subset G$ be a normal series of maximal length $n$ in $G$.
If $G_0 \neq \{e \}$, then we can construct another normal series $\{ e \} \subset G_0 \subset ... \subset G$ having a greater length $n+1 > n$. So $G_0 = \{ e \}$.

Now let

$\{e \} \subset ... \subset G_i \subset G_{i+1} \subset ... \subset G$

be a normal series of maximal length in $G$. Assume $\exists i \in \{0, ...,$ **maximal length**$\} \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is not simple. But then there exists a normal subgroup $K/G_i: \ G_i/G_i \subset K/G_i \subset G_{i+1}/G_i$. But then $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G_{i+1}$ such that $G_i \subset K \subset G_{i+1}$, and the normal series

$\{e \} \subset ... \subset G_i \subset K \subset G_{i+1} \subset ... \subset G$

has a greater length. A contradiction. Then $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is simple for any appropriate $i$ in our series.